# Add a foreign key to AspNetUsers

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm newbie in the use of `Asp.net Identity` . I'd like to add a profile image.
I added the required tables as indicated [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/677279/SQL-script-for-creating-an-ASP-NET-Identity-Databa). So I created a table and I'd like to add the foreign key constraint between it and `AspNetUsers`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ajt_photo ; 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ajt_photo (
  id_photo INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_user_fk varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  image Blob NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id_photo),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user_fk)
    REFERENCES AspNetUsers (Id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

I got an error indicates it is not possible to add the foreign key constraint!!

So, I need to know what is the reason? How can I fix my script?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Do the data types match in both tables? So `id_user_fk` is a `varchar(128)`, are you sure that `AspNetUsers.id` is also a `varchar(128)`?

Comment: @DavidG Yes , the fields has the same type ( varchar(128) ) plz see my edit

Comment: The source table uses `nvarchar(128)` and not `varchar(128)`.

Comment: @DavidG When I change it to `nvarchar(128)` I got this error `Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table 'ajt_photo'
`

Comment: Also, does the `AspNetUsers.id` have an index on it (is it a primary key for the table?)

Comment: This is the primary key constraint `CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
`

Comment: That's SQL Server syntax, not MySQL, I'm confused now...